# How to transform results of a select statement formatted as XML?

Tags: mysql, select, xml, export

When I run the command

```
mysql EvePlanataryExpenses --xml -uuser -p -e "SELECT sTransactionDateTime, SUM(sQuantity * sPrice) as 'profit' FROM sell GROUP BY sMonth;" |sed '/^\s*$/d'
```

I get the following output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resultset statement="SELECT sTransactionDateTime, SUM(sQuantity * sPrice) as 'profit' FROM sell GROUP BY sMonth" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <field name="sTransactionDateTime">2016-10-13</field>
    <field name="profit">1177089967.25</field>
  </row>
</resultset>
```

Is it possible to remove the `statement="text"` from the root element, and set the field name to something else than `<field name=""></field>` from the SQL query itself?

I saw something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420205/how-to-convert-a-mysql-db-to-xml) that I thought I could use, but can't make it work.

Or would I need to run the output through a parser (Java, PHP, something else) and get that to remove the statement from the root element and rename the field elements?

Comment: Can you switch from XML to JSON; it's much more civilized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query doesn't know (or care) how its results might be formatted by the client (the `mysql` program in this case), so no, you cannot influence the XML in the query itself. What you're looking for is called XSL transformation, for which there are command line tools (e.g. [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)) through which you can pipe your output.